# Is there an equivalent of Chrome's developer tools for Windows 8 HTML/JS/CSS apps?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-app, google-chrome-devtools

When web developing, developer tools such as those in Chrome are invaluable.

So is there an equivalent for Windows 8 Store apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found you can use the DOM Explorer and JavaScript Console inside Visual Studio as developer tools. DEBUG > WINDOWS > (whatever you want to show)

Comment: mind adding where can you install them/open them?

Comment: @Sathya I think they're preinstalled, but I don't know how to open, they just opened automatically inside visual studio.

Comment: Now as I write this post I realise I haven't mentioned visual studio... edited.